# Remove unique object on touchend event in multi-touch web application

Tags: jquery, web-applications, multi-touch, touch-event

Been pulling my hair out and googling non-stop but can't find a solution.  With the touchstart and touchmove events, I can retrieve a unique id from touches.identifier.  This is not possible as touches does not work with touchend event.

1. I want to create a div and assign the same id as the touches.identifer when touchstart happens.
2. Update x y strings in the div during the touchmove event.
3. Delete the div using jquery remove() on touchend event.

Step 3 is where I'm hitting a wall, i was going to use $("#"+e.touches.identifier).remove();

any suggestions to achieve step 3?

thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one such div present at any time? If you assign the div a class like "touch" on touchstart then you could select $("div.touch") on touchend.
I'm just starting to get into touch-events myself though, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Or maybe there's something in [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/) :)